# Unable to start the nodeapp through terminal

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu-14.04, webstorm

I have a node app locally and I normally run it using the run button in the web storm, which works fine. While I am documenting the project I came across this blocker: if I try running the same app through the terminal using the command: node app.js , the server starts but the browser throws and error stating "This site can’t be reached" "localhost refused to connect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this myself.. since I used the scaffolding app and it stores info related to server at bin/www, so we will not be able to run the app using the command : node app.js but instead we could run the app using nodemon(which I installed globally on my machine)

Love nodemon for this awesome feature <3 :)

Answer (score 2):

Because the port is occupied.

You can change it using `app.listen({port})...`

or

linux:

`export PORT=4500
node server.js`

windows:

`set PORT=4500
node server.js`